# Python: relativedelta issue with pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, relativedelta

I have a problem after changing reading the excel file from **pd.read_excel()** to **pd.read_csv()** for below code.

When using pd.read_excel(), no below error pops up，but for performance issue, I still need to use pd.read_csv().

I have tried to changemany thanks in advance:

```
  t_date=pd.read_csv('D:/data.csv',encoding='utf-8',parse_dates=True)
  t_date['Item Creation Date'] = t_date['Item Creation Date'].fillna('')
  t_date['Item Creation Date']=pd.to_datetime(t_date['Item Creation Date'])
  t_date['Order_WK']=t_date[['Item Creation Date']].apply(lambda x:(x['Item Creation Date']+relativedelta(weekday=SU)).strftime("%Y%m%d"),axis=1)

TypeError: ('can only concatenate str (not "relativedelta") to str', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: Your `"Item Creation Date"` column is a `string`, not a `datetime` object. You need to pass `parse_dates=["Item Creation Date"]` to `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: you need to convert `relativedelta(weekday=SU)` to a string. Can you let us know what is the value of variable `relativedelta(weekday=SU)` as of now?

Comment: try replacing `x['Item Creation Date']+relativedelta(weekday=SU)` with `(x['Item Creation Date']+relativedelta(weekday=SU)).strftime("%Y%m%d")`. You can change `%Y%m%d` to your desired format ( `%m%d%Y` or  `%m%d%Y%H:%M:%S`....and so on)

Comment: @Héléna so, you may have `NaT` in the column `x['Item Creation Date']`. try fixing that first by either removing it or coercing it to get a date vaue instead of `NaT`

Comment: Please provide your input dataframe or at-least `t_date['Item Creation Date']`

Comment: @Héléna `.fillna('')` will also not work because `x['Item Creation Date']+relativedelta(weekday=SU))` has to be a date for `.strftime("%Y%m%d")` to work on it.

Comment: @moys  hi since I have "pd.to_datetime(t_date['Item Creation Date'])" , it is already been converted to  a date and should work for .strftime("%Y%m%d"), is my understanding correct?

Comment: @PMende  hi  parse_dates is added in pd.read_csv(...parse_dates=True), is that what you suggest? tks~

Comment: @Héléna please double check if all rows of column `t_date['Item Creation Date']` are dates. Even if one of them is also not a date (`NaT` or something like that, even blank), it will not work. If you can provide your input dataframe or at-least `t_date['Item Creation Date']` , we can help you better.

Comment: @moys  I see the reason now, many thanks